# using bash and curl to send file from server to client

Tags: server, bash, scripts

so i am trying to solve this lab on deterlab.net. but i cant figure out exactly how to create my bash file with the curl instruction in order to created a web traffic stream between the client and the server nodes by writing a script at the client that each second gets index.html from the server. The full purpose of this lab is to create a DOS attack and flood the created traffic after. The attacking part i can manage but the bash file with the curl i cannot.this is what i have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
# traffic between client and server
x=1
a = 1000000
while [ x < a]
do
    curl -o index.html https://localhost/2389
    x =x + 1
done
```

Can someone please help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Leverage a C-style `for` looping construct:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((x=1; x<1000000; x++)); do
    curl -o index.html https://localhost/2389
done
```

In `((x=1; x<1000000; x++))`:

- `x=1` initializes `x` to 1
- `x<1000000` is the condition, the loop will run as long as `x` is less than 1000000
- `x++` increments `x` with adding 1 after each run of loop

---

You have some syntactic mistakes:

- To refer to the value of a variable, you need `$variable` i.e. put the `$` in front, also it is almost always desired to have quoting around that to prevent word splitting and glob expansion: `"$variable"`
- There can't be any whitespace around `=` while declaring variables,s o `a = 1000000` is wrong. You need `a=1000000`
- `[ x < a]`: here `[` does not support arithmetic operators like `<`, you need to use `-lt` (less than), otherwise it is just doing string comparison. You need: `[ "$x" -lt "$a" ]`. Also consider using the `[[` builtin of `bash` instead of `[`. For arithmetic operation you can use `((` too, this will allow you to use all the arithmetic operators
- `x =x + 1` is a syntax error, you can not have whitespace around `=` while declaring variables as mentioned earlier, also `+ 1` after `x` is meaning nothing and shell will treat it as separate word (command) with variable `x=x` in it's environment. you need `(( x=x+1 ))` or `((x+=1))` or simply `(( x++ ))`.

So your script can take the final form:

```
#!/bin/bash
# traffic between client and server
x=1
a=1000000
while (( x < a )); do
    curl -o index.html https://localhost/2389
    (( x++ ))
done
```

Comment: works great. but could you tell me if that curl code is cu=orrect for what i need it for?

Comment: @andrew.hans Well, the `curl` command is not running in each second, each `curl`instance will do the fetching, and writing to `index.html`,  then the loop will continue further. if you want them to run asynchronously, you need to send them to background by add `&` at the end:  `curl -o index.html https://localhost/2389 &`, in that case you should add a file extension like `-o $x_index.html` to keep track of the instance that is doing the write, otherwise there will certainly be race conditions. Check if this suits your purpose.

Comment: no it didn't work. I was just wondering if that script could be used for what i need to get done.

Comment: @heemayl typical "gimme the codez" drive-by.  +1 for effort!  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby Thanks. I should try to use my experience often. :/

Comment: I am not asking for the code specifically. i am just trying to figure out if the curl command is correct for what i need it for.

Comment: @andrew.hans That's an opinion, and opinions are off-topic here.  The above answers your original question, and as you've never accepted an answer on this site before: If one of the answers *solved your problem*, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of its text, which means [Yes, this answer is the most useful of all](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**